# Accessing .ASPX page on password protected site from within same site

Tags: asp.net, security

We recently migrated our staging server to a new hosting provider and setup forms authentication from within the hosting account control panel so that crawlers and unwanted visitors could not access it.

Now we are finding at least one area of the site's logic that is failing due to HTTP 401 Unauthorized.

There is a section of the site that generates PDF for site users. The conversion is from HTML to PDF. The source pages are .ASPX written in C#. The generate .HTM by downloading the ASPX files using their URL, such as http://www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx.

Now that the site is password protected, these routines fail with the HTTP 401 and I'm not sure how to overcome this. We don't want to remove the site authentication because we don't want anything accessing it.

Can anyone point me on how to code around this so that our internal routines will have access to local pages like we need?

**EDIT**

Some more detail. Since this is just a development site, I performed a quick and dirty configuration from within the hosting provider's control panel to enable Folder Security. I added the root folder '/' and then created 2 users. This works fine. When I go to the site I am prompted with what appears to be a forms authentication dialog box. I enter my username and password, access is granted.

I've noted that this configuration created 4 files in my root /' web site folder. They are .htaccess, .htpasswd, .htgroup, and .htfolders. This site has a lot of folders. Configuring each one in this manner would be time consuming and tedious. Therefore the '/' root configuration.

Our purpose is to block access to crawlers/search engines and also casual visitors who stumble onto the hostname.

This configuration causes the side effect that a small part of the site can no longer access it's own pages via http:// without getting an HTTP 401 error. What I would love to do is configure all of this using `<security><ipSecurity>`, blacklist all except for myself and the web site, but the provider doesn't install the needed IP module to do this.

The C# code that is receiving the HTTP 401 is:

```
webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webrequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
webrequest.Timeout = 600000;
resp = webrequest.GetResponse();
```

I've also tried:

```
CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
credCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("username", "password"));
webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webrequest.Credentials = credCache;
webrequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
webrequest.Timeout = 600000;
resp = webrequest.GetResponse();
```

Both methods receive HTTP 401 Unauthorized. I really don't want to fix this in the C# code because this security issue will not exist on the live site. I would much rather perform this configuration in web.config and/or the .ht* files if needed.

So, I am wondering, is there anything I can place in web.config that will help? Does anyone see a problem the way this is setup? (Other than it's not working! :P)

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can remove authentication for just one page as follows.

```
<location path="mypage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: This is helpful. There are 7 pages total that need to be authorized. Do they all go on the same line somehow? Or a new section for each? Although, I have been looking to see if there is a way of allowing localhost or my hostname to have access to the local site altogether. Is this possible? Like setting path= to * maybe and allow users= localhost? This doesn't work because I've tried it, but maybe there is a way.

Comment: You have to create new section for each!  I was wondering if the logged-on user has access to mypage.aspx your code should work! Are you tring to access this page when no one is logged in? Can you show us the code?

Comment: Cherian, the problem isn't with users. There are only 2 of us that access the site currently and we have logins that work. The problem is that the C# codebehind is unable to access its own pages using http://. For example, using WebResponse and HttpWebRequest. The purpose is for HTML to PDF generation. The HTML is rendered by accessing the .ASPX pages using http://

Comment: Ok. Then try the above solution. You have to create new section for each!

Comment: Would your example work for an entire folder? There are about 10 files that would need this authorization. :S

Comment: Yes. It will work. Just give the folder name. Have you tried request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; ? This will use the logged-on user credentials to access the webrequest.

Comment: I edited the post with additional information. Thank you for your help, I think I owed you more details to be able to help better.